# Fitnesse deployment practices

Tags: testing, integration-testing, fitnesse

Is there some documentation on the best ways to organize the deployment of Fitnesse for use in projects?

I have many questions:
How should it be stored? Should the whole fitnesse root be stored in SVN?  How do you deal with acceptance tests that span multiple svn repositories?

We have some code that runs only on linux (server) and other code that runs only on windows (client) that make up the complete system, how do you run these? Do you have multiple Finesse servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the company that I work we are setting up a FitNesse for Functional Tests integrated with SVN and Selenium.

Here is our basic idea:

- Store FitNesse in a repository on SVN (yes, the root)
- Store Selenium tests in another repository on SVN (per project and both .html and .java TestNG generated)
- Use Hudson to automate checkouts from SVN and put everything to run on a QA Environment. If a FitNesse acceptance test span across multiple svn repositories, Hudson is able to download and build the projects. This way, FitNesse does not need to deal with this issue.

We are still integrating the tools. We also use Jira, Testlink, Sonar and MediaWiki.